# What kind of mathematical object is the quantized Yang-Mills field?

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

I have a question regarding the mathematical description of Yang-Mills theories. In classical Yang-Mills theory, the Yang-Mills field (or field strength in physical language) is given by the curvature $F$ of the corresponding principal fibre bundle, which means that it is a Lie-algebra valued 2-form.

From mathematical Quantum Field Theory, I know that quantized fields are normally described as operator-valued distributions...

How does this two concepts combine in the case of quantized Yang-Mills Theory?

Comment: The operator's matrix elements are curvatures.